# DataTable is not populated correctly

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a C# application. Here is a piece of my code:

```
private const string SqlLatestFiles = "SELECT Name, [FileId],[Filename],Age,[ModifiedDT],RcvDT,[Records],[InvalidRecords],[V2Stage],[V1Stage],[FileType] FROM MyDB.[dbo].[LatestFiles] order by [ModifiedDT] DESC;";
...
             using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlLatestFiles, myConnectionString))
         using (var dt = new DataTable())
         {
             da.Fill(dt);

...
         }
```

When I run the SqlLatestFiles in the SQL Server Management Studio, the selected data is correct. But when the DataTable dt is populated, V1Stage is 0. It didn't happen before this morning, and I doubt I could change anything. Does anybody have any idea why such thing could happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the underlying SQL Table to see what is in that compared to what your expecting?

Comment: The right data is some integer, sometimes same as in StageV2, sometimes different.

Comment: I don't think that the DataAdapter stopped working since this morning.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am so puzzled. But the fact is that the query should return the right data, but the DataTable is missing StageV1 data.

Comment: LukeHennerley, yes, I looked.

Comment: @DavidShochet: Do you know that you can inspect all fields of all rows in the table in the debugger window? Just click the loupe and then "DataTable Visualizer". Set a breakpoint after it was filled. You'll get a quick overview.

Comment: Yes, that is how I compare the expected data to the data in DataTable.

Comment: @DavidShochet: Why are you using the `ItemArray` to access the fields(note: before your last edit it was visible)? I would either use the DataRow indexer(f.e. `(int)row["V2Stage"]`) or better, the `DataRow` extension method `Field`:  `row.Field<int>("V2Stage")` with the name instead of the index. But in both cases i would prefer the name of the column instead of the ordinal.

Comment: I do use indexer, but I think it doesn't matter, because I can inspect the dt itself in the visualizer.

Comment: I recalled one thing that I changed yesterday: I created a copy of a database that is used in the LatestFiles view among other databases. I wonder if that may cause some confusion. It is the very database where the V1Stage should come from.

Comment: Yes! I removed the copy of the database, and now it works!

Comment: @DavidShochet So when you visualise the `DataTable` after filling it, the data is incorrect? I find that very hard to believe, seeing as it is a direct select from the SQL table that you say the data is correct in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recalled one thing that I changed yesterday: I created a copy of a database that is used in the LatestFiles view among other databases. It is the very database where the V1Stage should come from. 
And yes! I removed the copy of the database, and now it works!
I guess the DataAdapter somehow confuses the two databases that yesterday were exact copies of each other.